# Why does broadcasting give an empty tensor?

Tags: pytorch, broadcasting

```
x = torch.randn(1, 1, 0)

y = torch.randn(4, 1, 1)
```

```
(x+y)
```

tensor([], size=(4, 1, 0))

```
(x + y).shape
```

torch.Size([4, 1, 0])

shouldn’t it have been 4, 1, 1, just y?

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` has 3rd dimension equal to 0 - it's an empty tensor. The thirs dimension of `x` determines the third dimension of the result: `torch.Size([4, 1, 0])` - which is also empty.

try

```py
x = torch.randn(1,1,1)
```

Comment: But it should give y, why is it giving empty tensor, if I am adding an empty tensor to y, it should return y, or give an error stating invalid broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

It is so by design.

Tensor `x` has one dimension 0.

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(1, 1, 0)
print(x) # tensor([], size=(1, 1, 0))
```

These tensors are limited and I think the design is bad, but this is my opinion.
For instance such tensors cannot be concatenated.

```
static void check_cat_no_zero_dim(TensorList tensors) {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < tensors.size(); ++i) {
    auto& t = tensors[i];
    TORCH_CHECK(t.dim() > 0,
             "zero-dimensional tensor (at position ", i, ") cannot be concatenated");
  }
}
```

Also, what you noticed is inability to work with `+` operator.

So probable just like PyTorch tensors have the check if dimension is non-negative, it should be actually if `>0` check.

```
inline void check_size_nonnegative(IntArrayRef size) {
  for (auto x: size) {
    TORCH_CHECK(x >= 0, "Trying to create tensor with negative dimension ", x, ": ", size);
  }
}
```

Again this is just my point of view.